# Both of my Always Free instances were terminated

Tags: oracle-cloud-infrastructure

I had two always free instances running Ubuntu 18.04 LTS on ca-toronto-1. I logged in to the console today to see that both of them have been terminated. I didn't upgrade to a paid account after my trial expired but my understanding was that I could continue using the always free eligible instances. How can I find out why they were terminated?

I have 2FA enabled on my account with a strong passphrase so I don't think my account was compromised. There's nothing showing in work requests for either instance.

Answer (score 2):

This is a known issue and I believe Oracle's working on resolving the issue and hopefully, restore these "terminated" instances. Word is, emails have gone out to affected users. Meanwhile, if you're in a hurry to restore services, follow these steps:

1. Check that the boot volumes associated with the the terminated compute instances still exist.
2. If so, you can create a new instance from that boot volume.
3. If you were using ephemeral public IP addresses, then those would have been reassigned. I'd encourage you to create an assign a reserved IP address and then update your DNS records if they were previously associated to this instance.

Comment: Well… I've just been brought here by a web search, searching for an explanation why my Always Free instance was just terminated without a word of warning/explanation.